# Stuck at making a recursive query work in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I have a recursive table called `Hierarchies`. This is `show create table Hierarchies`:

```
CREATE TABLE `Hierarchies` (
  `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `ParentId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_Hierarchies_Unique_ParentId_And_Title` (`ParentId`,`Title`),
  KEY `FK_Hierarchies_ParentId_Hierarchies_Id` (`ParentId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Hierarchies_ParentId_Hierarchies_Id` FOREIGN KEY (`ParentId`) REFERENCES `Hierarchies` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

And I have created this view on top of it with CTE:

```
with recursive R as (
    select Id, ParentId, Title, '/' as Path
    from Hierarchies
    where ParentId is null
    union all
    select H.Id, H.ParentId, H.Title, Path + ('/' + H.Title) as Path
    from Hierarchies H
    inner join R
    on H.ParentId = R.Id
)
select
  h.*,
  R.Path
from R
inner join Hierarchies h
on R.Id = h.Id
```

This view works as long as I do not have children.

But as soon as I add children, then I get this error:

> Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '/'

I'm stuck at this point. I have no idea why it tells me that the `DOUBLE value` is `/`. I have searched and seen that people say this error is not relevant sometimes.

What should I do?

Comment: You are trying to apply an arithmetic operation to strings: `Path + ('/' + H.Title)`, whereas what you want is _concatenation_ using the [`CONCAT()` function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/concat/).

Comment: @mustaccio, if I use `select Slug + '/' + Title` it works. How comes that `Path + ('/' + Title)` becomes arithmetic, while `Path` is set to `'/'`?

Comment: [type conversion rules](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/type-conversion/). Good question about [select Slug + '/' + Title](https://dbfiddle.uk/D44dm595), it looks like double conversion is happening in a context that only produces a warning.